# How do I format text into two columns with headings in a text file using python?

Tags: python, text

I made a program that would output user names and Ids in a text file (this file is called task_3.1).

```
membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "w")
def ValidateMemberID(MemberID):
    if len(MemberID) !=6:
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[:1] == (MemberID[:1]).lower():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif MemberID[1:3] == (MemberID[1:3]).upper():
        return("Wrong Format")
    elif (MemberID[3:]).isdigit() == False:
        return("Wrong Format")
    else:
        return("Correct Format")

def inputdata():
    Name = input("Please input member name")
    MemberID = input("Please input member ID")
    ValidateMemberID(MemberID)
    if ValidateMemberID(MemberID) == "Correct Format":
           NameID = [Name," ", MemberID, "\n"]
    else:
        print ("Invalid MemberID")
    membership_data.writelines(NameID)

for x in range(2):
    inputdata()


membership_data.close()
```

It works fine and here is resulting text:

```
Ammar Amm123
Ammar Amm123
Ammar Amm123
Ammar Amm123
Ammar Amm123
```

My problem is that I need to format this text into two columns each with a header on them and I have no idea how to. I tried copying my friend's code and modifying it to fit mine but it wont work.

I ended up with this but with the import function I get a syntax error and without the import I don't get what I want.

```
from task_3.1 import NameID
Name = []
MemberID = []
membership_data = open("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\Pre-release\membership_data.txt", "a")
for line in (NameID):
    NameID = line.split()
    Name.append(NameID[0])
    MemberID.append(NameID[1])


membership_data.writelines("Name                    Member ID")
for i in range(len(Name)):
       print ("%-*s  %s" % (20, Name[i], MemberID[i]))

membership_data.writelines(Name)

membership_data.close()
```

Comment: What is `task_3.1.py`?  If you defined it, rename it so that it doesn't have decimals.

Comment: What's your question? How to format text or how to import that module?